# Okta invalid token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta-api

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: This aud claim is not equal to the configured audience"

when trying to hit a okta secured API using generated access token.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the audience present in the access token is not the same as the one that you are having in the JWT verifier.

You can use https://jsonwebtoken.io 506 to decode the access token and see the audience parameter that you are sending, in order to align it with the one you have in the verifier.

look for "**aud**": "xyz",